# Unable to scroll down 100% height section using iOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an issue with a website I'm making for my wedding invitation. The top section is displayed with a 100% height and you need to scroll down.

It works perfectly with FireFox / Chrome on my desktop but when viewing the website with iOS on an iPhone or iPad it won't scroll down.

I guess it's caused by the 100% body height. Anybody any idea how to make it work with iOS?

Code example: http://jsfiddle.net/ysLfL/

```
<html>
    <body>
        <header>
        </header>
        <section>
        </section>
        <section>
        <section>
```

...

css:

```
html, body, header{
    height:100%;
}

section{
    height: 1000px;
}
```

The header show fine, but I can't scroll to the next section.

Comment: Hello, i had the same problem...check this fix, it worked with me http://cantina.co/thought_leadership/ios-5-native-scrolling-grins-and-gothcas/ . Use this prefix -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);

Comment: @camiel Usually you add it to the list of properties for the same element that has the un-prefixed version.

Comment: @TylerH I understand but I'm not using the transform property..

Comment: @LuisP.A. thanks where do i need to add -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);? i added it to the header but that wont fix my issue...

Comment: I suppose that is in the body element that makes the scroll. Put in the body or the html.  body,html{-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);}. You must put this style where the element is making the scroll.

Comment: I already provide the code - body,html{-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);}.

Comment: @LuisP.A. added the code but doesn't seem to change anything... http://www.project-c.nl/test/

Comment: I think is a Skrollr bug, maybe you can try read post i think there is resolution:https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr/issues/265, or you can read here: https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr#what-you-need-in-order-to-support-mobile-browsers

Comment: @LuisP.A. thanks for your answer. It looks like a skrollr bug indeed. Unfortunately I didn't manage to fix it with the links you mentioned...

Comment: Problem solved by replacing the skrollr-body id, it was placed in the <body> and that caused the problem....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by replacing the skrollr-body id, it was placed in the body tag which caused the problem....